# Update array that is transmitted through props

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-dnd

The title might be a little bit ambigous, but I'll explain better :)

So I have this component DraggableGameSlots.tsx

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import DraggableGameSlot from "./DraggableGameSlot";

type DraggableGameSlotsProps = {
    numberOfAnswers: number,
    slotFor: string
}

function DraggableGameSlots(props: DraggableGameSlotsProps) {
    const [answers, setAnswers] = useState<string[]>(Array<string>(props.numberOfAnswers).fill("Drop here"));

    return (
        <div className="draggable-game-slots">
            {
                answers.map((val, index) => (
                    <DraggableGameSlot
                        className={props.slotFor === "text" ? "draggable-game-slot-for-text" : "draggable-game-slot-for-image"}
                        key={index}
                        answers={answers}
                        setAnswers={setAnswers}
                    />
                ))
            }
        </div>
    );
}

export default DraggableGameSlots;
```

and DraggableGameSlot.tsx

```
import { useEffect, useRef } from 'react';
import { useDrop } from 'react-dnd';
import './css/DraggableGameSlot.css';

type DraggableGameSlotProps = {
    className: string,
    answers: any,
    setAnswers: any
}

function DraggableGameSlot(props: DraggableGameSlotProps) {          
    const [{isOver}, drop] = useDrop(() => ({
        accept: "image",
        drop(item: {id: string}) {
            props.setAnswers([...props.answers, item.id]);
            console.log(props.answers);
        },
        collect: (monitor) => ({
            isOver: !!monitor.isOver(),
        })
    }))

    useEffect(() =>
        console.log(props.answers)
    );
      
    return (
        <div className={`draggable-game-slot ${props.className}`} ref={drop}>
            <span>Drop here</span>
        </div>
    )
}

export default DraggableGameSlot;
```

The logic is as follows:

I have an array of answers and I want to add new answers using react-dnd. The initial answers are "Drop here" (because they are not defined, only the slots with this text will appear - I'll implement this logic later).

So I have an array which contains all of the answers. I render them and everything is fine.

Then I have an useDrop hook from react-dnd - it is used to define the drop target for the draggable items. That is not the point of the posts either :)

I observed using the two console.logs from DraggableGameSlot, that for numberOfAnswers = 4, my array will be either length = 4 (initially) or length = 5, when I drop an answer and drop is called.

I expected each time an answer is dropped and props.setAnswers is called, a new answer will be added at the end of the array. Well, it doesn't work like this, actually, the 5th item is changed everytime.

e.g.

```
Drop here Drop here Drop here Drop here

I drag answer1:

Expectation: Drop here Drop here Drop here Drop here answer1
Behavior: Drop here Drop here Drop here Drop here answer1
OK

I drag answer2:
Expectation: Drop here Drop here Drop here Drop here answer1 answer2
Behavior: Drop here Drop here Drop here Drop here answer2

NOT OK
```

I suspect that it happens because props.answers doesn't update. I probably get a copy of its value when passing it through props, not a reference, so when I call setAnswers the answers array is updated only in DraggableGameSlots and props.answers stay the same.

Well, I don't want that.

Why is this happening and how can I make it work the way I intend? :)

Comment: My guess is the `key` property. Since `index` doesn't change so props(incl. answers) are cached. You can try `props.setAnswers(prevAnswers => [...prevAnswers, item.id])` and console.log inside it.

Comment: @bigless so how should I do it? Should I change the key property somehow or what?

Comment: Ah. Key is not an issue. When looking closer to [useDrop](https://react-dnd.github.io/react-dnd/docs/api/use-drop), it uses memoization(dependency array) and empty array as default value. You should add array of dependencies that can change(answers, setAnswers, etc) as second parameter to useDrop.

Comment: @bigless it worked this way. Thanks a lot for your comment, it has really saved me :) Please add it as an answer so I can accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When looking closer to [useDrop](https://react-dnd.github.io/react-dnd/docs/api/use-drop), it uses memoization(dependency array) and empty array as default value. You should add array of dependencies that can change(`answers`, `setAnswers`, etc) as second parameter to useDrop.